# VARCHAR parameter in INNER JOIN isn't working while INT parameter of the same table is working

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have three tables: Author, Author Catalog, Products. Author can have multiply books as books can have multiply authors, so I splitted the relation between Author and Production on two «1 to many».

I need to get all book names of one author.

I wrote this code, but it doesn't work with `VARCHAR` (returns no records).

```
CREATE PROCEDURE ViewAuthorBooks
    @fname VARCHAR,
    @midname VARCHAR,
    @lname VARCHAR
AS
BEGIN
    SELECT name_prod
    FROM production p
    INNER JOIN author_catalog c ON p.id_prod = c.id_book
    INNER JOIN author a ON c.author_id = a.id_author
    WHERE 
        (a.fname = @fname) 
        AND (a.midname = @midname) 
        AND (a.lname = @lname)
END
GO
```

So it works with INT.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE ViewAuthorBooks
    @id INT
AS
BEGIN
    SELECT name_prod
    FROM production p
    INNER JOIN author_catalog c ON p.id_prod = c.id_book
    INNER JOIN author a ON c.author_id = a.id_author
    WHERE a.id_author = @id
END
GO
```

Is there a way to solve my problem? Maybe I should use another JOIN with VARCHAR?

Comment: Always specify the length of a `Varchar(n)/NVarchar(n)`. What's the length of `author.fname`?

Comment: @Sami is right, in this context, `@fname VARCHAR` means `@fname varchar(1)`. That's why it's not working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you **omit** the length of a `VARCHAR` parameter, then you get you get a string of **exactly ONE character** in length! This is typically *not* what you want - so therefore: **ALWAYS** specify a reasonable **length** for any `VARCHAR` parameter or variable or column definition!

Try this:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE ViewAuthorBooks
    @fname VARCHAR(50),
    @midname VARCHAR(50),
    @lname VARCHAR(50)
AS
```

I'm almost certain now it **WILL** work just fine!

Comment: I just want to point out that this is always true in SQL Server, but not necessarily in other databases.